# What is the purpose of viagra spam?

Tags: email, spam, money

We all have gotten them:

> The reflection of your size will stay forever in her eyes.
>   Bigger pen!s gives you a bunch of benefits!
>   I have girls that ring me for sex now, its amazing!

Judging by the quantity of these messages in circulation, sending out Viagra (or similar) spam is clearly a huge business. The individuals/entities who send out these emails likely aren't doing it for kicks; if there wasn't money to be earned, they likely wouldn't be doing it for long.

**How is the money earned from Viagra spam?**

For example, are they just trying to trick people into sending them credit card information? Do the spammers actually earn money from selling medication, or do they earn money from referral bonuses to pharmaceutical sites?

Comment: If possible, please try to back up your answers with hard statistics, or better yet, links to research papers or reliable sources. I have tried to do research on this, but keep having to wade through "educated guesses" and unsubstantiated claims.

Comment: You already know all of this. So what you want us to do is query Google to find you research? I'm voting this as off-topic.

Comment: @LucasKauffman No, I really don't know exactly how they earn money. As I said in the comments, _most of the information I find from Google is guesswork and unsubstantiated information_. Ideally, I really want to find something like a reliable research paper where someone has responded to a couple hundred of these spam messages and observed and logged the results.

Comment: The key point is that sending spam is cheap, virtually free. Even if only one in a million actually buy some, these guys can still make a business out of it. Viagra is a common product because there's some shame in going to your doctor about it.

Comment: @paj28 the reason why people buy it online is because it's a lot cheaper than the real thing (albeit also a lot more dangerous). Viagra used to be very expensive because Pfizer had a patent on it which meant other pharmaceutical companies were not allowed to officially distribute it. In Europe the price plummeted from 85 USD for 4 pills to 14 USD for 4 pills when the patent expired.

Answer (score 4):

Not a research paper, but having worked on the spam filters for one of the largest email spam filtering services I've seen a lot of spam, and a lot of responses to spam.

Although the comments about 'free to send so all responses are profit' are accurate it's also the case that a lot of spam has another motivation over what appears in the email text, these include:

- if a person responds, their email address suddenly becomes valuable in itself (to other spammers, etc.) and can be monitized
- a lot of spam emails carry malicious payloads or are a precursor to phishing attacks (their links may seem to be dead and point to non existent servers etc.)
- buying from a spammer means providing financial information which can be further compromised, or sold to other criminals

So all is not as it seems for some spam emails.